# Wrap the constructor using class decorator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, decorator

What is the right way how to wrap the constructor of a class using class decorator? It should be enough if TypeScript is aware of the constructor signature, but the code below complains about the second class having an extra field. Since the decorated class only uses the super constructor that matches certain signature, my expectation was that specifying the target parameter type would be enough. I am sure I could achieve what I need by using `any` type wherever the compiler complains, but such relaxing kind of defies the purpose of using TypeScript.

```
interface IABC {
  a: number;
}
interface IABC_Type<T> {
  new(id: number): T;
}

function classDecorator(target: IABC_Type<IABC>): IABC_Type<IABC> {
  return class extends target {
    constructor(id: number) {
      console.log('@classDecorator constructor wrapper. id:', id);
      console.log('I\'ll square the id');
      super(id * id);
    }
  }
}

@classDecorator
class ABC {
  a: number = 0;
  constructor(id: number) {
    console.log('@ABC.constructor, id:', id);
  }
}

@classDecorator
class DEF {
  a: number = 0;
  x: number = 0;
  constructor(id: number) {
    console.log('@DEF.constructor, id:', id);
  }
}

const abc = new ABC(4);
const def = new DEF(5);
```